# Where are the canonical questions? Should I ask one?

Tags: discussion

I've just started with Android (just bought my first smartphone) and I would like to know answers to the questions that I'm sure should me already answered on any Android resource:

1. How do I revert the system back to original state? (asked [specific version](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67169/how-to-restore-stock-firmware-on-htc-one-mini) for my [HTC One mini](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_mini-5505.php), but didn't receive a full answer) Maybe I'd better ask how to backup and restore the system?
2. How do I root the phone? (and revert the changes back, for completeness' sake)
3. How do I flash a custom ROM?

I am surprised that I cannot see these generic questions on Android StackExchange. Should I ask them, or is there anything wrong with these questions?

Comment: Hi Nickolei. Welcome to the site. Canonical questions for 2 and 3 exist on the site. Factory reset is usually an option in the settings menu

Comment: @Flow Please provide links to canonical questions 2 and 3, as I can't find them. By 1 I mean revert the phone's software to the state that it came from the factory with; as far as I know, Hard Reset doesn't do this, it resets to the default state of the latest version of Android, instead.

Comment: [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/981)

Comment: @eldarerathis Great resource, thanks!

Comment: The answers can vary wildly per device, so these are not necessarily good canonical questions.

Answer (score 2):

We have a canonical question for 2.: [How do I root my Android device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/981)

But since more and more Android devices appear, we decided to allow one canonical question per device, as the process of rooting/flashing/restoring stack ROM varies at least between vendors, but sometimes also between devices.

See for example [this query](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=restore%20stock%20rom) which is about "restoring the stock ROM" which you asked for in 1.